# "session receiveSignalType" is never get called in opentok 2.1.7 version

Tags: ios, session, webrtc, opentok

I am working on video/audio/chat application by using opentok 2.1.7 version. I am able to send the signal but unable to listen signals in the code below:

```
_session receiveSignalType:@"signal" withHandler:^(NSString *type, id data, OTConnection *connection)
```

I have called function which will receive different signals once session is connected. Is there any specific mechanism need to follow to receive signals?

Answer (score 1):

Please update your iOS SDK, there are numerous bug fixes. Delegate for receiving signal has been changed to [received signal type](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/reference/Protocols/OTSessionDelegate.html#//api/name/session%3areceivedSignalType%3afromConnection%3awithString%3a).